# Changing this directory to point to another directory (Python) using a generic filename

Tags: python, linux, bash

I am having issues with a program I am forking (Pinguy Builder) Right now I just want to point this program to load a different gtk.glade skeleton/bare code which seems to be a glade project script. I don't know much about python. However I know few commands but how would I point this from /usr/share/PinguyBuiler to /usr/share/Flamesbuilder ? (Given the code below) Thanks. I don't want this project going away and I know a bit of bash to get through this as I plan on forking this bash and python scripted program.

ERROR CODE:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
CODE:


im#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
from PinguyBuildergtk import PinguyBuilder_gtk

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(FlamesBuilder_gtk.__file__)))
    #os.system('chmod a+x %s' % FlamesBuilder_gtk.__file__)

ERROR MESSAGE:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/flames/Documents/coding/flamesbuilder/flames builder/bin/PinguyBuilder-gtk", line 5, in <module>
    from FlamesBuildergtk import FlamesBuilder_gtk
```

ImportError: No module named FlamesBuildergtk

note: the file will be pointing to usr/share/FlamesBuilder or something like that. I know how the structurer works I just cant get it to point without cd. How would I fix this error? Thanks. - Flames

Comment: after import os line, add import sys;sys.path.append(r'put_path_to_FlamesBuildergtk_here')

Comment: Alright. I tried doing that but it won't let me point to the .glade file and it continues to point to the main /usr/share/PinguyBuilder. I apologize if this is a stupid question however, would I need to make a separate gtk or is it possible to point to the .glade file? P.S I cant use the normal directory like /usr/share or whatever because it says theres an invalid syntax

Comment: Try check your PinguyBuilder_gtk, looks like it importing FlameBuilder inside